# Код работает в консоли, но не работаете при вызове из-под Tumpermonkey

Tags: jquery

Пишу маленький юзерскрипт, застрял на моменте отправки на сервер *аякса* и получения ответа на него.

Если мой код протестировать в консоли, то все нормально, если же вызывать из-под *Tumpermonkey*, то страница становится белой и «висит» в этом режиме.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
if(/\/vacancy\/.*/.test(location)){
  $.ajax({
    url:'http://www.superjob.ru/vacancy/search/?
      period=0&t%5B%5D=4&catalogues=33&pay1=60000&pay0=0&experience=0&
      type_of_work=0&place_of_work=0&age=&pol=0&education=0&lng=0&
      lnlev=0&lang0=0&agency=0&moveable=0&active=0&detail_search=1&
      sbmit=1&extended=1',
    success: function(data){
      $('*').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `$('*').html(data);` - никогда так не делайте

Comment: да, а как?:
$(document) || $(window) || или как ?
прияем документ отказывался отрисовывать страницу, виндоу вроде что-то рисовал. но криво..
кстати никогда бы не подумал, но все решилось каким-то кастыльным идиотским способом...
аякс норм сработал с document.write(data);
поверг в шок меня)